# If a composition of functions is injective, must its components be injective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Assume that we have one to one function, that look like that:

$$f(g(x)).$$

We need to prove or dis-prove that:

I.$f$ is one to one.

II.$g$ is one to one.

I know the answers to booth questions, but my question is how can I show the function $g$ isn't one to one (not by showing an сounter example).

Comment: Hint: A) If $g(1)=g(2)$, how can you choose $f$ such that $f(g(1))\neq f(g(2))$. B) What if the domain of $g$ consists of a single point only?

Answer (score 22):

Assume $g(x)=g(y)$. Then $f(g(x))=f(g(y))$, hence $x=y$ because $f\circ g$ is injective. Thus $g$ is injective.

On the other hand, *unless* the function $g$ is onto, there is no reason for $f$ to behave nicely in places $g$ can't see. You'll easily find a counterexample using this intuition.

---

As a side note, I doubt there is a nice way of doing the part about $f$ without giving a counterexample. After all, what has to be done is to show that $f$ is *not necessarily* injective (of course it is *possible* that $f$ is injective). In other words, we have to show that *there exist* functions $f$ and $g$ (with appropriate domains and codomains) such that $f\circ g$ is injective and $f$ is not injective). The simplest existence proof is always a proof by example (though it may not be easy to *find* a counterexample).

The alternative would be a non-constructive existence proof, based ultimately on the Axiom of Choice. As the Axiom of Choice does not play a role for finite cases, it is hard to imagine that there is any *nice* proof along that path, given that a specific counterexample can be found in the realm of sets with two elements (the smallest cardinality where non-injective functions exist):

Let $B$ be a two element set, let $C$ be a singleton set, let $f$ be the only function $B\to C$. Then $f$ is not injective. Let $g$ be the only function $\emptyset\to B$. Then $f\circ g$ is vacuously injective.

Comment: +1, mainly for the statement *there is no reason for $f$ to behave nicely in places, $g$ can't see*.